# Different Ideals and their relationship to tame/wild ramification

Tags: number-theory

I am looking at Marcus' book "Number fields", precisely at exercises that lead to Hilbert's formula $k= \sum_{m\ge0} (|V_m|-1)$; that can be applied in turn to prove that, if $L/K$ is a Galois extension of number fields 
(for simplicity), $P$ is a prime in $\mathcal{O}(K)$, $Q$ is a prime in $\mathcal{O}(L)$ lying over $P$, and $Q^k || D_{L/K}$ ($Q^k$ perfectly divides  $D_{L/K}$), where $D_{L/K}$ is the different of $L/K$, then:

1) If $Q$ is tamely ramified over $P$ (i.e. ($p$,e)=1, where e=e($Q$|$P$) and $(p) _{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the contraction of $P$ to $\mathbb{Z}$)) it holds that k=e-1.

2) If $Q$ is wild over $P$ (i.e. it is not tame ) , then $k \ge e$.

I wondered whether these two statements still hold in the general case (when $L/K$ is not supposed to be normal), and whether it could be shown utilizing the result already known in the case of Galois extensions. I know that these results are more often obtained in the context of local fields, but as of now I've only taken a basic course in algebraic number theory, so I am not accustomed to "local stuff" yet, and therefore I'd like some ideal-theoretical answer (I've searched through the internet, but applications of the different almost always seem to be exclusively treated in local fields extensions).